# How to only calculate set fields with pgfplotstable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        x   y
        1   5
        2   10
        3   15
        4   0
        5   0
    }{\dataTable}

    % Transpose table
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[
        colnames from=x,
        input colnames to=x
    ]\dataTransposed{\dataTable}

    % calculate sum
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/assign/.code={
            \def\colsum{0}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
            \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
                \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
            }
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\colsum
        }
    ]{sum}\dataTransposed

    % calculate mean
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={
            \thisrow{sum}/(\pgfplotstablecols-2)
        }
    ]{mean}\dataTransposed


    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns/x/.style={string type}
    ]{\dataTransposed}
\end{document}
```

Which produces: [image: result of MWE]

However, I only want the mean value to use set rows (= values, that are not zero; above zero).
So with the given data, only x1-3 should be used for calculating the mean.
Currently, it calculates the sum of **all** rows, then divides it by the **column-count** [minus two; the first one is the x-y column, second is the now existing sum column].
Therefore, the correct result would be 10 [30 / 3], not 6 [30 / 5].

**How can I archive to either, count the number of set rows, or apply a filter to the expression, so that I get the correct results?**
[Only setting the existing values, thus removing x4-5 from the data, works, however, is not applicable in my case.]

I tried to loop over the data and find the first column that is equal to zero, then save it as a counter and use that value for the sum division, however, I couldn't succeed.
Maybe pgfplots-table also has a filter function, though I couldn't find anything for tables, only plots which didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just count the non-zero entries.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        x   y
        1   5
        2   10
        3   15
        4   0
        5   0
    }{\dataTable}

    % Transpose table
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[
        colnames from=x,
        input colnames to=x
    ]\dataTransposed{\dataTable}

    % calculate sum
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/assign/.code={
            \def\colsum{0}
            \def\colnum{0}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
            \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
                \ifnum\thisrowno{\col}=0
                \else
                  \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\colnum{\colnum+1}
                \fi
            }
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\colsum
            \xdef\colnum{\colnum}
        }
    ]{sum}\dataTransposed

    % calculate mean
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={
            \thisrow{sum}/(\colnum)
        }
    ]{mean}\dataTransposed


    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns/x/.style={string type}
    ]{\dataTransposed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
It works perfectly and does exactly what it should.
However, sadly, only in the MWE.

I tried to implement your attempt in my original document, but it fails there.
LaTeX complains about `Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` and `Missing number, treated as zero.` in the line `\ifnum\thisrowno{\col}=0`.

I don't really understand how it can work in the MWE, but not in the document.
Could it be, that this line fails, when more than two rows (I am working with four) are involved?

Comment: @Sakul6499 I do not think this is the reason. Rather, it seems to me that you do not have an integer there. You could just define `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{\thisrowno{\col}}` and then do `\ifnum\itest=0`. Does that work?

Comment: This works perfectly!